# zeta of imaginary numbers

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

So the Riemann hypothesis was dealing with the real part of the $s$ be $\frac12$ and I was wondering if it is possible to take zeta of imaginary numbers and if it is, how would you proceed to do so?

Comment: In the same way you evaluate most values: using a suitable representation of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation.  See also the many formulas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: Also https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Zeta%5BI%5D

Comment: $\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} - \frac12 + s\int_1^\infty (\lfloor x \rfloor -x+\frac12) x^{-s-1}dx$ is valid for $ \Re(s) > -1$